# A* algorithm can't find path to the goal

Tags: java, algorithm

I've been struggling with an implementation of the A* algorithm in Java. What I am trying to do is to load in a tile map created in a text file (with spaces, obstacles, start and goal marked by different characters), create a node map from it and be able to run A* on the map. When I run my A*, however, it checks a few nodes around the start before the open list runs out and it returns null. I've been messing around with this for the last few days and I can't figure out why it fails. It's probably something silly, but any help would be appreciated.

A* Implementation:

```
public ArrayList<Node> calculateShortestPath(int startHeight, int startWidth, int goalHeight, int goalWidth) {
    map.setStart(startHeight, startWidth);
    map.setGoal(goalHeight, goalWidth);

    if (map.getGoal().isObstacle()) {
        return null;
    }

    map.getStart().setDistanceFromStart(0);
    closedList.clear();
    openList.clear();
    openList.add(map.getStart());
    Collections.sort(openList);

    while (!openList.isEmpty()) {
        Node currentNode = openList.get(0); //the list should be sorted, so this should produce the node with the lowest f value
        if (currentNode.equals(map.getGoal())) {
            return reconstructPath(currentNode);
        }

        openList.remove(currentNode);
        closedList.add(currentNode);

        for (Node neighbour : currentNode.getNeighbourList()) {
            System.out.println(neighbour);
            boolean neighbourIsBetter;
            if (closedList.contains(neighbour)) {
                continue;
            }
            if (!neighbour.isObstacle()) {
                float neighbourDistanceFromStart = (currentNode.getDistanceFromStart() + map.getDistanceBetweenNodes(currentNode, neighbour));
                if (!openList.contains(neighbour)) {
                    openList.add(neighbour);
                    Collections.sort(openList);
                    neighbourIsBetter = true;
                } else if (neighbourDistanceFromStart < currentNode.getDistanceFromStart()) {
                    neighbourIsBetter = true;
                } else {
                    neighbourIsBetter = false;
                }
                if (neighbourIsBetter) {
                    neighbour.setPreviousNode(currentNode);
                    neighbour.setDistanceFromStart(neighbourDistanceFromStart);
                    neighbour.setHeuristicDistanceFromGoal(getEstimatedDistanceToGoal(neighbour.getHeight(), neighbour.getWidth(), goalHeight, goalWidth));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Some map creation methods:

```
private void createMap() {
    Node node;
    map = new Node[mapHeight][mapWidth];
    for (int x = 0; x < mapHeight; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < mapWidth; y++) {
            node = new Node(x, y);
            map[x][y] = node;
            if (obstacles[x][y] == 1) {
                node.setObstacle(true);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void registerEdges() {
    for (int x = 0; x < mapHeight - 1; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < mapWidth - 1; y++) {
            Node node = map[x][y];
            if (!(x == 0)) {
                node.setNorth(map[x - 1][y]);
            }
            if (!(y == mapWidth)) {
                node.setEast(map[x][y + 1]);
            }
            if (!(x == mapHeight)) {
                node.setSouth(map[x + 1][y]);
            }
            if (!(y == 0)) {
                node.setWest(map[x][y - 1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the compareTo override used to sort the open list

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Node otherNode) {
    float thisTotalDistanceFromGoal = heuristicDistanceFromGoal + distanceFromStart;
    float otherTotalDistanceFromGoal = otherNode.getHeuristicDistanceFromGoal() + otherNode.getDistanceFromStart();

    if (thisTotalDistanceFromGoal < otherTotalDistanceFromGoal) {
        return -1;
    } else if (thisTotalDistanceFromGoal > otherTotalDistanceFromGoal) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

All the other methods are getters, setters and other support methods. I'm using the Manhattan distance for the heuristic. I am aware that I create and access the map by the height then the width (y, x vs. x, y). It stems from the fact that this is how the file is read in (lines then characters in line), and I opted to maintain it throughout, as the switching back and forth was initially causing issues for me.

Here is a little bit about what I have tried. I have printed out the node map during testing, so I know it is being created correctly. I have also printed out information about the nodes as they being accessed in the algorithm, and the height and width values are being assigned correctly and the algorithm is starting in the right place. I have used breakpoints to confirm that my compareTo method is the one being called for sorting, and I sort anytime a node is added to the openList. I simply cannot spot the issue.

EDIT:
Additional Code:

Complete Map Class:

```
public class Map {
private final int mapWidth;
private final int mapHeight;
private Node[][] map;
private final int[][] obstacles;
private int startHeight = 0;
private int startWidth = 0;
private int goalHeight = 0;
private int goalWidth = 0;

public Map (int mapWidth, int mapHeight, int[][] obstacles) {
    this.mapWidth = mapWidth;
    this.mapHeight = mapHeight;
    this.obstacles = obstacles;

    createMap();
    registerEdges();
}

private void createMap() {
    Node node;
    map = new Node[mapHeight][mapWidth];
    for (int x = 0; x < mapHeight; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < mapWidth; y++) {
            node = new Node(x, y);
            map[x][y] = node;
            if (obstacles[x][y] == 1) {
                node.setObstacle(true);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void registerEdges() {
    for (int x = 0; x < mapHeight - 1; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < mapWidth - 1; y++) {
            Node node = map[x][y];
            if (!(x == 0)) {
                node.setNorth(map[x - 1][y]);
            }
            if (!(y == mapWidth)) {
                node.setEast(map[x][y + 1]);
            }
            if (!(x == mapHeight)) {
                node.setSouth(map[x + 1][y]);
            }
            if (!(y == 0)) {
                node.setWest(map[x][y - 1]);
            }
        }
    }
}

public Node[][] getNodes() {
    return map;
}

public void setObstacle(int height, int width, boolean isObstacle) {
    map[height][width].setObstacle(isObstacle);
}

public Node getNode(int height, int width) {
    return map[height][width];
}

public void setStart(int height, int width) {
    map[startHeight][startWidth].setStart(false);
    map[height][width].setStart(true);
    startHeight = height;
    startWidth = width;
}

public void setGoal(int height, int width) {
    map[goalHeight][goalWidth].setGoal(false);
    map[height][width].setGoal(true);
    goalHeight = height;
    goalWidth = width;
}

public int getStartHeight() {
    return startHeight;
}

public int getStartWidth() {
    return startWidth;
}

public Node getStart() {
    return map[startHeight][startWidth];
}

public int getGoalHeight() {
    return goalHeight;
}

public int getGoalWidth() {
    return goalWidth;
}

public Node getGoal() {
    return map[goalHeight][goalWidth];
}

public float getDistanceBetweenNodes(Node node1, Node node2) {
    return 1 * (mapWidth + mapHeight);
}

public int getWidth() {
    return mapWidth;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return mapHeight;
}

public void clear() {
    startHeight = 0;
    startWidth = 0;
    goalHeight = 0;
    goalWidth = 0;
    createMap();
    registerEdges();
}
```

}

Complete Node Class:

```
public class Node implements Comparable<Node>{
private Map map;
private Node north;
private Node east;
private Node south;
private Node west;
private ArrayList<Node> neighbourList;
boolean visited;
float distanceFromStart;
float heuristicDistanceFromGoal;
Node previousNode;
int height;
int width;
boolean isObstacle;
boolean isStart;
boolean isGoal;

public Node(int height, int width) {
    neighbourList = new ArrayList<Node>();
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
    this.visited = false;
    this.distanceFromStart = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    this.isObstacle = false;
    this.isStart = false;
    this.isGoal = false;
}

public Node (int height, int width, boolean visited, int distanceFromStart, boolean isObstacle, boolean isStart, boolean isGoal) {
    neighbourList = new ArrayList<Node>();
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
    this.visited = visited;
    this.distanceFromStart = distanceFromStart;
    this.isObstacle = isObstacle;
    this.isStart = isStart;
    this.isGoal = isGoal;
}

public Node getNorth() {
    return north;
}

public void setNorth(Node north) {
    //replace the old Node with the new one in the neighborList
    if (neighbourList.contains(this.north)) {
        neighbourList.remove(this.north);
    }
    neighbourList.add(north);

    //set the new Node
    this.north = north;
}

public Node getEast() {
    return east;
}

public void setEast(Node east) {
    //replace the old Node with the new one in the neighborList
    if (neighbourList.contains(this.east)) {
        neighbourList.remove(this.east);
    }
    neighbourList.add(east);

    //set the new Node
    this.east = east;
}

public Node getSouth() {
    return south;
}

public void setSouth(Node south) {
    //replace the old Node with the new one in the neighborList
    if (neighbourList.contains(this.south)) {
        neighbourList.remove(this.south);
    }
    neighbourList.add(south);

    //set the new Node
    this.south = south;
}

public Node getWest() {
    return west;
}

public void setWest(Node west) {
    //replace the old Node with the new one in the neighborList
    if (neighbourList.contains(this.west)) {
        neighbourList.remove(this.west);
    }
    neighbourList.add(west);

    //set the new Node
    this.west = west;
}

public ArrayList<Node> getNeighbourList() {
    return neighbourList;
}

public boolean isVisited() {
    return visited;
}

public void setVisited(boolean visited) {
    this.visited = visited;
}

public float getDistanceFromStart() {
    return distanceFromStart;
}

public void setDistanceFromStart(float distanceFromStart) {
    this.distanceFromStart = distanceFromStart;
}

public float getHeuristicDistanceFromGoal() {
    return heuristicDistanceFromGoal;
}

public void setHeuristicDistanceFromGoal(float heuristicDistanceFromGoal) {
    this.heuristicDistanceFromGoal = heuristicDistanceFromGoal;
}

public Node getPreviousNode() {
    return previousNode;
}

public void setPreviousNode(Node previousNode) {
    this.previousNode = previousNode;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(int height) {
    this.height = height;
}

public int getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public void setWidth(int width) {
    this.width = width;
}

public boolean isObstacle() {
    return isObstacle;
}

public void setObstacle(boolean isObstacle) {
    this.isObstacle = isObstacle;
}

public boolean isStart() {
    return isStart;
}

public void setStart(boolean isStart) {
    this.isStart = isStart;
}

public boolean isGoal() {
    return isGoal;
}

public void setGoal(boolean isGoal) {
    this.isGoal = isGoal;
}

public boolean equals(Node node) {
    return (node.height == this.height) && (node.width == this.width);
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Node otherNode) {
    float thisTotalDistanceFromGoal = heuristicDistanceFromGoal + distanceFromStart;
    float otherTotalDistanceFromGoal = otherNode.getHeuristicDistanceFromGoal() + otherNode.getDistanceFromStart();

    if (thisTotalDistanceFromGoal < otherTotalDistanceFromGoal) {
        return -1;
    } else if (thisTotalDistanceFromGoal > otherTotalDistanceFromGoal) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Height: " + this.getHeight() + " Width: " + this.getWidth();
}

//for debugging
public void printObstacle() {
    if (isObstacle) {
        System.out.print("1 ");
    } else {
        System.out.print("0 ");
    }
}
```

}

Complete AStar Class:

```
public class AStar {
private Map map;
private ArrayList<Node> closedList;
private ArrayList<Node> openList;
private ArrayList<Node> wayPoints;

public AStar(Map map) {
    this.map = map;

    closedList = new ArrayList<Node>();
    openList = new ArrayList<Node>();
}

public ArrayList<Node> calculateShortestPath(int startHeight, int startWidth, int goalHeight, int goalWidth) {
    map.setStart(startHeight, startWidth);
    map.setGoal(goalHeight, goalWidth);

    if (map.getGoal().isObstacle()) {
        return null;
    }

    map.getStart().setDistanceFromStart(0);
    closedList.clear();
    openList.clear();
    openList.add(map.getStart());
    Collections.sort(openList);

    while (!openList.isEmpty()) {
        Node currentNode = openList.get(0);
        if (currentNode.equals(map.getGoal())) {
            return reconstructPath(currentNode);
        }

        openList.remove(currentNode);
        closedList.add(currentNode);

        for (Node neighbour : currentNode.getNeighbourList()) {
            System.out.println(neighbour);
            boolean neighbourIsBetter;
            if (closedList.contains(neighbour)) {
                continue;
            }
            if (!neighbour.isObstacle()) {
                float neighbourDistanceFromStart = (currentNode.getDistanceFromStart() + map.getDistanceBetweenNodes(currentNode, neighbour));
                if (!openList.contains(neighbour)) {
                    openList.add(neighbour);
                    Collections.sort(openList);
                    neighbourIsBetter = true;
                } else if (neighbourDistanceFromStart < currentNode.getDistanceFromStart()) {
                    neighbourIsBetter = true;
                } else {
                    neighbourIsBetter = false;
                }
                if (neighbourIsBetter) {
                    neighbour.setPreviousNode(currentNode);
                    neighbour.setDistanceFromStart(neighbourDistanceFromStart);
                    neighbour.setHeuristicDistanceFromGoal(getEstimatedDistanceToGoal(neighbour.getHeight(), neighbour.getWidth(), goalHeight, goalWidth));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private ArrayList<Node> reconstructPath(Node node) {
    ArrayList<Node> path = new ArrayList<Node>();
    while (!(node.getPreviousNode() == null)) {
        wayPoints.add(0, node);
        node = node.getPreviousNode();
    }
    this.wayPoints = path;
    return path;
}

private float getEstimatedDistanceToGoal(int startX, int startY, int goalX, int goalY) {
    float dx = Math.abs(goalX - startX);
    float dy = Math.abs(goalY - startY);

    return dx + dy;
}

public ArrayList<Node> getWayPoints() {
    return wayPoints;
}
```

}

Relevant Main Code:

File Reading, Map Creation and AStar Call:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> readMap = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    int height = 0;
    int width = 0;
    int startHeight = 0;
    int startWidth = 0;
    int goalHeight = 0;
    int goalWidth = 0;

    File fileMap = new File("./map.txt");
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileMap))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            char[] characters = line.toCharArray();
            readMap.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
            for (char character : characters) {
                if (Character.isWhitespace(character)) {
                    readMap.get(height).add(0);
                } else if (character == 'X') {
                    readMap.get(height).add(1);
                } else if (character == 'S') {
                    readMap.get(height).add(0);
                    startHeight = height;
                    startWidth = width;
                } else if (character == 'G') {
                    readMap.get(height).add(0);
                    goalHeight = height;
                    goalWidth = width;
                }
                width++;
            }
            width = 0;
            height++;
            mapFile.add(line);
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    height = 0;
    width = 0;
    int[][] obstacleMap = new int[readMap.size()][readMap.get(0).size()];
    for (ArrayList<Integer> row : readMap) {
        for (Integer column : row) {
            obstacleMap[height][width] = column;
            width++;
        }
        width = 0;
        height++;
    }

    Map map = new Map(obstacleMap[0].length, obstacleMap.length, obstacleMap);
    AStar pathfinder = new AStar(map);
    shortestPath = pathfinder.calculateShortestPath(startHeight, startWidth, goalHeight, goalWidth);
```

Neighbor Node Printout While Running:

```
Height: 11 Width: 0
Height: 12 Width: 1
Height: 13 Width: 0
Height: 10 Width: 0
Height: 11 Width: 1
Height: 12 Width: 0
Height: 11 Width: 1
Height: 12 Width: 2
Height: 13 Width: 1
Height: 12 Width: 0
Height: 10 Width: 1
Height: 11 Width: 2
Height: 12 Width: 1
Height: 11 Width: 0
Height: 11 Width: 2
Height: 12 Width: 3
Height: 13 Width: 2
Height: 12 Width: 1
Height: 10 Width: 2
Height: 11 Width: 3
Height: 12 Width: 2
Height: 11 Width: 1
```

This is as far as it makes it. (12, 0) is the start node (for this map). Also, diagonal paths are not necessary, so this only looks at north, west, east and south nodes.

Comment: First, this is a poor choice of data structures. Don't sort in every iteration. Use a priority queue. And for the closed list, a HashSet. Second, the only way the algorithm can fail as you say is not to process all neighbors. You didn't provide enough code to figure out how that's happening. SO works best when you provide a small version of your code that compiles and displays the bad behavior you need help with.

Comment: I'm not blind to the inefficiencies. I was more focused on getting the logic out, then optimize later (I'm teaching myself A* as I do this). But thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: There is far too much state mutation occurring, which may lead to the issue -  at the core, *only* the current cost should be updated. However,  this question / problem is not sufficiently refined. Way too much code. Also,  'width' and 'height'  are being used incorrectly,  which is just confusing.